# What it is the interpretation of the below picture in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, geometric-interpretation

somone sent me the below picture and He asked me to give him its interpretation regarding set theory ? but I ask alos about its geometricall interpretation ?

[image]

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with group theory. Perhaps he meant set theory.

Comment: yes , He meant set theory not group theory

Answer (score 3):

This is a common way in beginning set theory to prove that the rational numbers can be matched one to one with the integers. Start following the arrows and add one to the count each time you see a black fraction. The red fractions are not in lowest terms and have already been counted.

There's little to do with geometry here - just that in the picture the row wntries have the same numerator while the column entries have the same denominator.